# React-icons module not found: can't resolve '../lib"

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

I've just installed react-icons and tried to import an icon and I get this error.

```
./node_modules/react-icons/fa/index.esm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../lib' in 
'/Users/nathanbarry/Programming/personalsite/node_modules/react-icons/fa'
```

I've looked at the package in the node_modules and there IS a lib folder there.

I've tried reinstalling it and that didn't work. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer, but I ran this

```
npm uninstall react-icons
npm install react-icons@4.2.0
```

and that resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).